# fill all nan values in a dataframe with values from a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like this

```
index      a      b      c
0          0      0      1
1          nan    1      2
2          0      1      3
3          1      nan    4 
4          1      0      5
5          nan    0      6
6          nan    nan    7
```

I want to fill the first 2 columns(actually first 20ish) with the value from the last column, i.e.

```
index      a      b      c
0          0      0      1
1          2      1      2
2          0      1      3
3          1      4      4 
4          1      0      5
5          6      0      6
6          7      7      7
```

I was thinking using something like df.iloc[:,0:1].fillna(df['c']), however it only works when i am selecting one column, if more than one is selected everything will remain nan. i want to fill first 20ish column all using the values from the last column using iloc(or using index not column names).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
out = df.fillna(dict.fromkeys(list(df),df.c))
Out[206]: 
     a    b  c
0  0.0  0.0  1
1  2.0  1.0  2
2  0.0  1.0  3
3  1.0  4.0  4
4  1.0  0.0  5
5  6.0  0.0  6
6  7.0  7.0  7
```